# How can I set a field value based off another field's value at runtime in Activiti

Tags: activiti

[image]

I have two field in my Activiti form. I have two fields `Dated` and `Date Received` which both take date values. I am trying to find which Activiti Service best suits my task.

My task is this: The `Dated` field will take the value of the `Date Received` field when the `Date Received` is populated with a date. So e.g. if `Date Received` has a date `12/03/1990`, then at runtime the `Dated` field will also take that value.

I tried to implement the following logic but I don't know if it's the right approach to achieve this.

```
@Component("helloWorldBean")    
public class HelloWorldBean implements JavaDelegate{

        @Override
        public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

            RuntimeService runtime = execution.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService();
            runtime.setVariable(execution.getId(), "addLetter-targetdatesladate", "HELLO WORLD");
        }
}
```

Would this be the right approach to access the runtime service? I also checked the Activiti User Guide under the section for `dynamic field Injection` which is [here](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html?_ga=1.12424375.2096367007.1475683496#serviceTaskFieldInjection).

Comment: Even though runtimeservice aquisition looks ok, you can use execution.setVariable("addLetter-targetdatesladate", "HELLO WORLD") directly.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin, thanks I will try that. Does execution occur even when someone enters a value in a field? Or does execution only occur at the beginning/end of a process?

Comment: Entering value in a field is part of userTask, and userTask is being executed under one of process executions. Meanwhile setVariable sets process level variable, not execution/task local variable.
Generally you can get different execution for every async part of process, but often activiti reuses execution for synchronous parts. 
Do you want to set task variable instead of process variable?

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin I want to set a Task Variable which will change dynamically depending on another field on the same form. So as the example in the question, if `Date Received` has a date `12-03-1990` then I want the `Dated` field to also take that value `12-03-1990` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the blatant plug here, but the Brazos UI framework from BP3 handles exactly this scenario. Process 9or task) variables are automatically updated within the context of the process as they are updated on a page/form. And updates can be chained so that an update of one variable automatically drives the update of another variable within the process itself (not just on the form).

This way, multiple users can be subscribed to the same set of process (or task) variables and immediately see updates made by others.

Likely this answer will be pulled, but it sounds like this would satisfy you use case very well.

Brazos Developer Edition is free to download at www.bp-3.com

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a job for `javascript` instead of `java`. Set the value of the `dependent field` by using the value from the `dependee` field (i.e. when user select a field the other field should be populated) on value change event.